# Eliminating Recursion in my Code

Tags: java, recursion, do-while

My code has recursion—execute() calls again() and etc. I was thinking of using a do/while loop at main() or execute() to eliminate this, but if I do so, the string for asking the user if they want to play again will be out of scope. I can't have the console2 before or after the loop—it would not make sense to ask if they want to play again at the start.
Feel free to point out any flaws with my beginner code as there are probably many. Thanks.

Here's my code so far—with the recursion:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;


public class RockPaperScissors {


    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            execute(); 
    }


    public static void execute(){       

        System.out.println("This program will allow you to play \n\"Rock, Paper, Scissors\" against a computer.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter 'r' for Rock, 'p' for Paper, or s for Scissors.");
        System.out.println("Enter 'w' to have an insta-win for that round. Enter '-1' at anytime to exit program.");

        String info = userInput();
        int value = guessCode();
        decideOutcome(value, info);
        again();
        }


        public static String userInput() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);  
        String s = console.next();
        return s;
    }

        public static int guessCode() {
        Random r = new Random ();   
        return (r.nextInt(3)+1); // Random integer between 1 and 3;
    }

    public static void decideOutcome(int i, String j) {

        try {
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("records.txt", true));

            if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")|| j.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                count++;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You've won! Computer picked scissors.");
                        output.println(count + " Win ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You've tied.... Computer also picked rock.");
                        output.println(count + " Tie ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("You've lost. Computer picked paper.");
                        output.println(count + " Loss ");
                        break;
                    }           
            } else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")|| j.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                count++;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You've lost; Computer picked scissors.");
                        output.println(count + " Loss ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You've won! Computer picked rock.");
                        output.println(count + " Win ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("You've tied.... Computer also picked paper.");
                        output.println(count + " Tie ");
                        break;
                    }
            } else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")|| j.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                count++;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You've tied.... Computer picked scissors.");
                        output.println(count + " Tie ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("You've lost; Computer picked rock.");
                        output.println(count + " Loss ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("You've won! Computer also picked paper.");
                        output.println(count + " Win ");
                        break;
                    }
            } else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("w")) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("You've effortlessly defeated the computer!");
                output.println(count + " Win ");
            } else if (j.equals("-1")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!"); // need to find way to reach end.

                if (count == 1) { // If the user terminates after the first match.
                    System.out.println("You've played a single match.");        
                } else if (count > 1) { // Anything more than 1 match played upon termination.
                    System.out.println("You've played " + count + " matches total.");   
                } else { // This is for exceptions when user inputs gibberish for their sign and then 'no' for the second input.
                    System.out.println("No matches were played.");  
            }           
                System.out.println("Good Bye!");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You didn't input the right thing.");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File was not found; try again");
        }
    }

    public static void again() {
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (Type in 'y' for Yes or 'n' for No.)");

            Scanner console2 = new Scanner (System.in);

            String t = console2.next();

            while (t.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")||t.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                execute(); // 
            }  
            if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || t.equals("-1")) {
                System.out.println("Hope you had fun! I'm sure I've had just as much fun with making this program! Good Bye!");         

                if (count == 1) { // If the user terminates after the first match.
                        System.out.println("You've played a single match.");        
                } else if (count > 1) { // Anything more than 1 match played upon termination.
                        System.out.println("You've played " + count + " matches total.");   
                } else { // This is for exceptions when user inputs gibberish for their sign and then 'no' for the second input.
                        System.out.println("No matches were played.");              
                }   
                System.exit(0);

            } else { // If the user doesn't input 'yes' or 'no.'
                System.out.println("Not the proper response, but it's assumed that you don't want to continue.");   
                if (count == 1) { // If the user terminates after the first match.
                    System.out.println("You've completed a single match."); 
                } else if (count >= 2) { // Anything more than 1 match played upon termination.
                    System.out.println("You've completed " + count + " matches total.");
                } else { // The user haphazardly messes up both inputs.
                    System.out.println("No matches were finished.");
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new boolean variable `keepPlaying`, initialize it to `true` and then once the player wishes to exit the game, set it to false.

Then in the main method say:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("This program will allow you to play \n\"Rock, Paper, Scissors\" against a computer.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter 'r' for Rock, 'p' for Paper, or s for Scissors.");
    System.out.println("Enter 'w' to have an insta-win for that round. Enter '-1' at anytime to exit program.");

    while (keepPlaying == true) {
        again();
    }
}
```

Place the input code to the start of the `again()` method.

```
private static void again() { // Maybe rename to play()?
    String info = userInput();
    int value = guessCode();
    decideOutcome(value, info);
    .....
}
```

you then wont need `execute()`. As another answer suggested, methods and variables should only be public unless they are needed by another class.

Answer (score 0):

An easy change would be a do-while in the main method `execute`, and test in the while the result of `again` (it might be a simple boolean), to know if the user wants to continue or not.

By the way, in my opinion `execute` should be the only public method and there's no reason to have everything `public static`. `count` is a candidate for just being `private`. Otherwise, re-accessing the class would not ensure its initial value is 0, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code. There were a few repeated lines of code that could have been re-used for diff conditions. Have modified them. Compare it with your code to check what has been changed. Hope it helps.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

public static int count = 0;
private static Scanner console;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    console = new Scanner(System.in);
    execute();
}

public static void execute() {
    String info = null;
    boolean accept;
    do {
        System.out
                .println("This program will allow you to play \n\"Rock, Paper, Scissors\" against a computer.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out
                .println("Enter 'r' for Rock, 'p' for Paper, or s for Scissors.");
        System.out
                .println("Enter 'w' to have an insta-win for that round. Enter '-1' at anytime to exit program.");

        info = userInput();
        int value = guessCode();
        decideOutcome(value, info);
        accept = again();
    } while (!info.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && accept);
}

public static String userInput() {
    String s = console.next();
    return s;
}

public static int guessCode() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return (r.nextInt(3) + 1); // Random integer between 1 and 3;
}

public static void decideOutcome(int i, String j) {
    try {
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(
                "records.txt", true));
        if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("w")) {
            count++;
            System.out
                    .println("You've effortlessly defeated the computer!");
            output.println(count + " Win ");
        } else if (j.equals("-1")) {
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing!"); // need to find way
                                                        // to reach end.

            if (count == 1) { // If the user terminates after the first
                                // match.
                System.out.println("You've played a single match.");
            } else if (count > 1) { // Anything more than 1 match played
                                    // upon termination.
                System.out.println("You've played " + count
                        + " matches total.");
            } else { // This is for exceptions when user inputs gibberish
                        // for their sign and then 'no' for the second
                        // input.
                System.out.println("No matches were played.");
            }
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("r")
                || j.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("p")
                || j.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")
                || j.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
            count++;
            switch (i) {
            case 1:
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've won! Computer picked scissors.");
                    output.println(count + " Win ");
                }
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've lost; Computer picked scissors.");
                    output.println(count + " Loss ");
                }
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")
                        || j.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've tied.... Computer also picked scissors.");
                    output.println(count + " Tie ");
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've tied.... Computer also picked rock.");
                    output.println(count + " Tie ");
                }
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                    System.out.println("You've won! Computer picked rock.");
                    output.println(count + " Win ");
                }
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")
                        || j.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've lost; Computer picked rock.");
                    output.println(count + " Loss ");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've lost. Computer picked paper.");
                    output.println(count + " Loss ");
                }
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") || j.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've tied.... Computer also picked paper.");
                    output.println(count + " Tie ");
                }
                if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")
                        || j.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                    System.out
                            .println("You've won! Computer picked paper.");
                    output.println(count + " Win ");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("You didn't input the right thing.");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File was not found; try again");
    }
}

public static boolean again() {
    System.out
            .println("Do you want to play again? (Type in 'y' for Yes or 'n' for No.)");
    String t = console.next();
    if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        return true; //w
    } else {
        if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("n")
                || t.equals("-1")) {
            System.out
                    .println("Hope you had fun! I'm sure I've had just as much fun with making this program! Good Bye!");
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Not the proper response, but it's assumed that you don't want to continue.");
        }
        if (count == 1) { // If the user terminates after the first match.
            System.out.println("You've played a single match.");
        } else if (count > 1) { // Anything more than 1 match played upon
                                // termination.
            System.out
                    .println("You've played " + count + " matches total.");
        } else { // This is for exceptions when user inputs gibberish for
                    // their sign and then 'no' for the second input.
            System.out.println("No matches were played.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
 }
```